# What sorting algorithm is this, and can it be improved?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, haskell

I have been trying to work on making a good sorting algorithm for a while. At first I thought that insertion sort would be a good idea but with large lists it runs into a similar problem as the Haskell quicksort does with memory.

I then tried to make up my own sorting algorithm that works the same as my insertion sort but it tries to cut down on memory usage and repetition a little bit to improve speed:

```
modsort' :: (Ord a, Eq a) => [a] -> [(a, Int)]
modsort' [] = []
modsort' ls@(x:xs) = insert (x, count x ls) $ modsort' (filter (\i -> i /= x) xs)
    where
        insert :: (Ord a, Eq a) => (a, Int) -> [(a, Int)] -> [(a, Int)]
        insert i1 [] = [i1]
        insert i1@(x, _) i2@((y, f):xs)
            | x <= y = i1:i2
            | x >  y = (y, f) : insert i1 xs
        count :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int
        count i xs' = count' i xs' 0
            where count' _ [] n = n
                  count' i (x:xs) n
                    | i == x    = count' i xs (n + 1)
                    | otherwise = count' i xs n

uncompress :: [(a, Int)] -> [a]
uncompress [] = []
uncompress ( (v, n) : rest) = repeat' v n ++ uncompress rest
            where repeat' _ 0 = []
                  repeat' i n = i : repeat' i (n - 1)
```

Compared to some other algorithms for Haskell I have seen online this one seems a little longer. It scales pretty well for very long lists with a lot of repetition (eg. language: words, letters), but completely flops when the list has little to no repetition (Data.List sort was able to sort [10000,9999..1] in 2 seconds, this took 50).

Is there a way to improve this or some small thing I am overlooking, or should I just try to make a different/better algorithm for sorting?

Comment: This is an insertion algorithm right? You could apply the same "trick" to a mergesort algorithm.

Comment: I'm curious: why did you think insertion sort, a suboptimal O(N^2) algorithm, would be a good idea to start with? Merge sort looks a better candidate to me.

Comment: I actually tried out a mergesort algorithm and it performs much faster for lists with no repetition but this outperforms it for repetitive lists. I will try to apply this to a mergesort next.

Comment: This is "just" run-length encoding of an insertion sort's output, and so cannot change the worst-case asymptotics (except for finite alphabets) because runs cannot be guaranteed to exist. ...but if you must do run-length encoding of your output, I recommend the implementation `sort' = toAscList . fromList` using the [multiset](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/multiset-0.3.4.1/docs/Data-MultiSet.html) package -- it will have worst-case O(n log n) runtime, the best possible for comparison-based sorts.

Comment: And, if you want linear time sorting, you can use the discrimination package: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/discrimination

Comment: Did you try applying run-length encoding to mergesort? There's no obvious impediment.

Comment: @BobDalgleish Copying from a comment of mine [on this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/5xa82l/algebraic_graphs_with_class_asking_for_feedback/): "linear-time sorting sounds so good, but please do a few small benchmarks before you dive deep. I was playing with it just this week, and in my (admittedly very simplistic) test discrimination used more memory and more time than `Data.List.sort`, right up to the point that my OOM-killer kicks in, so although it may scale better you may not be able to reach the scales where it matters."

Comment: How did `Data.List.sort` take 2 seconds to sort 10000 values in reverse order on your system? That should be nearly instantaneous on basically any hardware that can run Haskell. It's the second best case for the algorithm - it should be only a little slower than just calling reverse.

Comment: Already sorted ascending or descentding input such as `[10000,9999..1]` is a best case for `Data.List.sort` and it is O(n). It should never take 2 seconds. Make sure you don't count the displaying time of the resulting list on GHCI. `Data.List.sort` is one of the best sorting algorithms ever.